# Vuejs testing - Ava - Changing propData

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, ava

Im trying to change the propData passed into a component to monitor and check the component.

Im expecting the last console log in this code block to be 5 but its still 2.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import test from 'ava';

import AnimateNumber from './../src/components/AnimateNumber.vue';

function instance(propsData) {
    let N = Vue.extend(AnimateNumber);
    return new N({propsData});
}

test('..', t => {

    let vm2 = new Vue({
        data: {
            a: 2
        }
    });

    let vm = instance({number: vm2.a}).$mount();

    // vm.displayNumber is just a copy of the number prop passed in.
    console.log(vm.displayNumber); // 2

    // Set to 5
    Vue.set(vm2, 'a', 5);

    console.log(vm2.a); // 5

    Vue.nextTick(function () {
        console.log(vm.displayNumber); // 2 (Expected 5)
    });

});
```

Comment: Why do you expect 5 out of  `vm` when you are only setting 5 on `vm2`?

Comment: Because vm2.a is passed in as a prop to vm. All im trying to do is change the propData passed into a component and make sure the components internal data has changed.

Comment: Got a repository somewhere?

Comment: Sadly no sorry. But AnimateNumber is a very simple component, all its really doing is changing some data and then rendering based on the prop 'number' provided. All im trying do is change the prop and check via my test.

Answer (score 0):

I would use petrol to test vue js components https://github.com/MGMonge/petrol

in that case your test would be

```
import AnimateNumber from './../src/components/AnimateNumber.vue';
import VueTestCase from "petrol/core/VueTestCase.js";

export default class AnimateNumberTest extends VueTestCase {

    /** @test */
    it_display_the_correct_number() {
        this.SUT = this.mount(AnimateNumber, {number: 2});

        this.assertEquals(2, this.SUT.displayNumber);

        this.SUT = this.mount(AnimateNumber, {number: 5});

        this.assertEquals(5, this.SUT.displayNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i would still like to work out why what i have is not working as expected.